# How do I use token to call Google API with node and express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, google-authentication

I'm building a small Node/React app where I'm trying to implement OAuth2 Google to request the Google Analytics API. I'm using Passport.js to handle the authentification.

Then from what I understand reading this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) I need to `use token to call Google API`. how do I do this?

I have the token being passed into a variable:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/google/callback",
    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/error", session: false }),
    function(req, res) {
        var token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect("http://localhost:5000/?token=" + token);


    }
);
```

What I'd like to do for example is getting a list of all View (Profiles) for the authorized user.
How do I pass the token in this example?

```
function listViews() {
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
        accountId: '~all',
        webPropertyId: '~all'
  });
  request.execute(printViews);
}
```

I tried with this:

```
router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
    googleAccounts.management.profiles.list(
      {
        accountId: '~all',
        webPropertyId: '~all'
      },
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error: ' + err)
          res.send('An error occurred')
        } else if (data) {

          Console.log(data)

        }
      }
    )
})
```

but I have an error `Error: Login Required.`

Comment: can you provide more information about `gapi` and `googleAccounts` ? Where are these defined?

Comment: the googleAccounts is defined with this `const googleAccounts = google.analytics('v3')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the token, you can set it before the api call with:

```
function listViews() {
  gapi.client.setToken{
    access_token: <token-here>
  })
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.profiles.list({
        accountId: '~all',
        webPropertyId: '~all'
  });
  request.execute(printViews);
}
```

See [Google API Javascript Client Reference](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/reference.md#----gapiclientsettokentokenobject--)